# How to solve the problem of growth Docker cache

Tags: docker

Build projects .NET based on sdk and aspnet docker images.

When build images on a PC, a large amount of cache of about 20 GB (approximately 3-5 image builds) is created, and when you reach the limit in Docker Desktop settings, no image can be assembled.

I control space on PC `docker system df`, then `docker system prune -a`

Today found command `docker builder prune -f` to remove only cache, but...

But then docker upload both sdk and aspnet images, and
assembly takes about 18 minutes, instead of 9 min

As a result of the assembly I get 4 images by ~ 250 Mb, but the cache after one assembly reaches 3 Gb

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          4         0         427.9MB   427.9MB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     80        0         2.452GB   2.452GB

docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
webuicontrol        test      820995769b28   4 minutes ago   303MB
sqlservicecontrol   test      42534d41499f   5 minutes ago   242MB
opcuacontrol        test      234ab5c5a120   5 minutes ago   242MB
sharecontrol        test      ade90fad5138   6 minutes ago   265MB
```

The question is, how do I keep the cache from growing?
Why does every time the image is reassembled and the cache grows?
Tell me with tips

Comment: You want cache to speed up things without using disk? That's not going to work. Your cache size and image sizes looks completely normal. You can run `docker builder prune -f` sometimes, like weekly, to remove unused/obsolete caches but thats all.

Comment: thought that Docker Decktop had a feature to clean the cache itself when the limit was exceeded, so as not to use the scheduler.
Or maybe I can think of a script that has been turned on by someone who checks the set limit and, if necessary, activates `docker builder prune -f`

Comment: Actually there is garbage collector: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/cache/garbage-collection/ but for Docker Desktop idk how to configure. But again, you don't want to delete your caches if you want to take advantage of it, building faster.